# how to add tdlib to android studio project

Tags: android, tdlib

I'm trying to add TDlib to my android studio project but I can't. in core.telegram.org/tdlib just tells me to use the android prebuilt library but does not say how to add it to an existing project to start building a custom client. 
if I open the unzipped tdlib with android studio it appears as a valid project structure with missing graddle files, if I select to add missing files automatically it fails in graddle syncing with `ERROR: Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.`
I'm stuck with this

I'm working on windows 10 build 1903, android studio 3.5 and the latest zip downloadable on telegram site

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Add `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` in your app level build.gradle file

Comment: that line is there but android studio don't want it